# Password protecting the settings / extensions page in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, password-protection

Is there any way to protect with password the settings page in Google Chrome? Exactly, the extensions page.

I do not want anyone in my household except me to have access to the settings. The only solution I found was an extension that protects with password the whole Google Chrome web browser, but I need to protect only the settings page.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is a way to do that. Chrome, [or better Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home), is open source software available under a permissive, BSD-Like license.

You are free to introduce the changes you need, e.g. a rudimentary hiding of the settings behind a username and password.

Comment: can you please explain how?

Comment: @ecoe: he probably meant that you can modify the source code ;-)